# Correlations and associativity

Tags: experimental-physics, statistics, correlation-functions, data-analysis

Suppose one has a set of data $D$ and a theoretical model $M(A,B,C)$ one wants to fit to it by obtaining the best fitting values of the parameters $A,B,C$, which in principle are free. Plotting the best fitting values of the pairs $(A,B)$ and $(B,C)$ one finds that $A$ and $B$ are correlated by a powerlaw $A\sim B^{x}$, and $B$ and $C$ with a powerlaw as $B\sim C^{y}.$ Does it mean that $A$ and $C$ should be correlated as well by a powerlaw of the form $A\sim C^{xy}?$

Comment: In my opinion, the answer is "yes".  Your mathematical model should consist only of terms which are independent of one another.  Try for a different mathematical model with fewer terms.

Comment: The reason the phrase "in my opinion" is used here is because there are a few different usages of the word "correlated," whose definition is, like all words, at least partly a matter of opinion. The commenter was allowing for the possibility that someone might disagree with him based on a different definition of correlation, so that semantic debates could be avoided.

Comment: @user115376, that's correct.  Also note that correlation is not causation.  Hopefully, you have a very good theoretical basis for your mathematical model.

Comment: Thanks both for the comments, but my question arises when I obtain:
1) $log A=-1.06+1.62 log B$
2) $log A=-3.84+2.09 log C$
3) $log B=-0.68+0.81 log C.$ 

As you may see: from 1) and 2), I should obtain $log B=(1.06-3.84)/1.62+(2.09/1.62)log C,$ which doesn't correspond to 3) as for example, $0.81\neq (2.09/1.62)$.

Comment: What physical basis did you use for your equations?  Are you willing to send me your raw data?

Comment: OK, @user115376.  Obviously, you want to keep the data to yourself.  My comment on your equations: curve fits are definitely not unique.  Any number of different correlations can be made to fit a particular data set.  My guess is that your 3 equations are telling you this exact thing.  If you have a physical reason to select one equation out of all the possibilities, try that equation.  Otherwise, you will not be able to resolve the differences that you have noted.